# How to use SimSun-ExtB to bold chinese text

Tags: chinese-postman

I need to make simsun(Chinese) words in bold font for my project(Themelyaf). For that , I have added simsunb.ttf in fonts file. Also, I have added in renderer as below:

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addfont(FONTDIR+"simsunb.ttf",
                           BaseFont.Identity_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

But still it is not working. Can anyone please suggest how to apply simsun bold?